# Are sequences themselves metric spaces with the inherited metric?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I have been asked to show whether a sequence $(p_n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space with the inherited metric $d(x,y) = |x-y|$

It seemed to me at first to be a slightly odd question because we tend to think of sequences as elements of a metric space not a metric space.

What is the answer to this question? Trivially, I can think of $(p_n)$ as the set of positive integers. Then $d(x,y) = |x-y|$ is a legit metric on the integers, therefore $(\{p_n|n \in \mathbb{N}\}, d(x,y))$ is as good of a metric space as any

In general, are all sequences defined on $(M,d)$ themselves metric spaces with the inherited metric $d$?

Comment: You mean as subspaces? But would not the functional relation $\{(n,p_n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ be a better reflection of the sequence as sequence? What would $d(x,y)$ be in that case? What would happen to periodic sequences?

Comment: I think you'll only get a pseudometric, unless it is assumed that the sequence is injective.